# Stop physics for single object in Corona SDK?

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk, corona-storyboard

I'm having a problem when I try to restart my game. I pause the physics, then when the user clicks the button, the physics are supposed to restart. When I put in physics.start(), though the game crashes. So, I was wondering if it's possible to pause one physical object and then change it's position on the screen.  I'm kind of a newb so any answer will be helpful.

```
local physics = require( "physics")
physics.start( )


local crate1 =  display.newRect( display.contentWidth/2,display.contentHeight/2, 40,40)
physics.addBody( crate1, { density=4.0, friction=0.3, bounce=.4} )
crate1.bodyType = "dynamic"
crate1.isBodyActive = true
crate1:setFillColor( 1,0,.3)


sky = display.newRect( display.contentWidth/2, .5, display.contentWidth, 0.000000000000000000001)
physics.addBody( sky, {density=4.0, friction=0.3, bounce=1.5} )
sky.bodyType = "static"



ground = display.newRect( display.contentWidth/2, display.contentHeight, display.contentWidth, .00000000001 )
 physics.addBody( ground, {density=4.0, friction=0.3, bounce=1.5 } )
 ground.bodyType = "static"


 rightWall = display.newRect( display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight/2, 1, display.contentHeight )
 physics.addBody( rightWall, {density=4.0, friction=0.3, bounce=1.5} )
 rightWall.bodyType = "static"


 leftWall = display.newRect(1, display.contentHeight/2, .0000000001, display.contentHeight )
 physics.addBody( leftWall, {density=4.0, friction=0.3, bounce=1.5} )
 leftWall.bodyType = "static"


physics.setGravity( 0, 3 )


local function handleCollisionOnDelay( event ) 
  local obj = event.source.object

  obj.isBodyActive = false
end


local function onLocalCollision( self, event )
  if ( event.phase == "began" ) then
    local dr = timer.performWithDelay( 10, handleCollisionOnDelay )

    dr.object = self
    crate1.x = display.contentWidth/2
    crate1.y = display.contentHeight/2
  end
end

crate1.collision = onLocalCollision
crate1:addEventListener( "collision", crate1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

use isBodyActive property
http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/Body/isBodyActive.html
good luck

Comment: Thanks for the link, I tried it out, and when my object (crate1) collides with something, it stops moving.  That is not exactly what I am trying to accomplish, though.  The crate has to be able to hit things for the user to gain points, but I want it to stop moving when it hits one of the borders of the screen.  I tried to change it, but I cannot figure out how it works.  My code is below.  If you have any advice, please say so.

Comment: Actually the code is above.  I edited my question because I couldn't fit it in the comment.

Comment: set obj.gravityScale = 0 and obj:setLinearVelocity(0,0); it ahold stop the obj

Comment: I don't think I understand exactly how I would do that.  Would you mind showing me in my code above?  I'm just trying to learn.